# Exception FopFactoryBuilder

Tags: java, apache-fop

I'm using the fop-2.1.jar, xmlgraphics-commons-2.1.jar and JRE 1.6.when running the application, I have a exception message:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/fop/apps/FopFactoryBuilder
at com.demo.employee.<init>(employee.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:370)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:323)
```

and line 44:

```
FopFactoryBuilder builder = new FopFactoryBuilder(new File(".").toURI());
```

this is my class path

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/avalon-framework-impl-4.3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/fop-2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/xml-apis.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-bridge-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-anim-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-awt-util-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-css-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-ext-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-svg-dom-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-extension-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-gvt-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-parser-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-dom-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-svggen-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-transcoder-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-util-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/batik-xml-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="dist/PORTAL-INF/private/lib/xmlgraphics-commons-2.1.jar"/>
```

Please advise me

Comment: check whether the particular jar exist in your classpath

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne: what 's the particular jar you refer ?

Comment: Your class path is somehow not correct when you are running your application. The particular JAR being mentioned is perhaps 'fop-2.1.jar', which have you already listed in your classpath list. But the error clearly indicates that the JVM is unable to load the class definition for org/apache/fop/apps/FopFactoryBuilder.

Comment: @Jaywalker: could you please advise the particular jar if I use fop-1.1 jar

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/fop/1.1